# How to mount a webdav server on Windows XP which uses port 8083 rather than 80?

Tags: windows-xp, webdav

I'm trying to map a webdav share on Windows XP using...

```
net use w: http://myserver.com:8083/webdav/ /User:smith passwd
```

I get "System error 67 has occurred.  The network name cannot be found."

I can connect on OSX via `http://smith:passwd@myserver.com:8083/webdav/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907306/en and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831805/en and http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-webdav-network-drive.html

> Windows XP can only connect to port 80 and can only map to a sub
>   folder and not the root directly.